# NgModel not Updating for Input of Type Radio in Angular Testing

Tags: angular, karma-runner

I have the following `input` in my Angular 2 application:

```
<input 
    id="radio-{{geo.id}}"
    name="radio-geos"
    type="radio" 
    [value]="geo.value"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedGeo">
```

The `selectedGeo` is bound to `public selectedGeo: string;`

I'm writing the following for my input element:

```
it('should select the US Home Region', (done) => {
        // Arrange
        const component = TestBed.createComponent(regionComponent);

        // Act
        component.detectChanges();
        const usGeoRadioButton = component.debugElement.query(By.css('#radio-0'));                

        usGeoRadioButton.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
        component.detectChanges();
        const selectedGeo = component.componentInstance.selectedGeo;

        // Assert
        component.whenStable().then(() => {
            expect(selectedGeo).toBe('US');
            done();
        });
    });
```

After running the tests in Karma, I notice that the radio button is not being clicked on and the `selectedGeo` is not being updated. My test fails because `selectedGeo` comes back as undefined.

I'm not sure why this is happening and I've done some research on `dispatchEvent` and how the `[(ngModel)]` is updated but I haven't been able to figure this out.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your input tag be formatted like this (with no brackets around value and ng-model):

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="string" value="string" [name="string"]...>
```

Doc link: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

Comment: I should’ve specified earlier that this is an Angular 2 application. I’ve fixed it.

Comment: I am also stuck in a similar scenario. Could you provide your fix?